# What are the CMG-relevant banks according to Basel III?

Tags: basel

I'm going through Basel III [monitoring workbook](http://www.bis.org/bcbs/qis/biiiimplmoniwb_mar13.xls) and [instruction](http://www.bis.org/bcbs/qis/biiiimplmoninstr_feb13.pdf).

There's one row in "General Info -> A) General Bank Data -> 1) Reporting Data" part: "CMG-relevant: Yes/No?"

I wonder what does this mean? 
Is "CMG" the Capital Monitoring Group mentioned in [Basel Committee on Banking Supervision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_Committee_on_Banking_Supervision)
which banks are CMG-relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CMG means "Crisis Management Groups"